# Trying to add mobile swipe to lightbox2

Tags: php, jquery

So i've got a lightbox and i'm wanting to add hammer.js to my site. I have the following functions.php file. The two hammer js files i'm loading exist in my js folder within my child theme.

```
<?php
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

// BEGIN ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
// AUTO GENERATED - Do not modify or remove comment markers above or below:

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_light', 30 );
function theme_light() {



wp_enqueue_style( 'lightbox', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/lightbox.css', array(), '4.3.0' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'lightbox2',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/lightbox.js', array( 'jquery' ), '3.3.0', true );

    wp_enqueue_script('swiper', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js/hammer.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('swiper1', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js/jquery.hammer.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.0', true);



}




// END ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION




if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css' ) ):
    function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array( 'bootstrap','font-awesome' ) );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css', 10 );

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts', 20 );
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'simpleshift_public' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/public.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true);
}

add_action('wp_head','my_conditional_script',0);


function my_conditional_script() {
    if ( is_page('magdalena-morey') || ('ophelia-redpath') || ('john-glover') ) {
        remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array('easyFancyBox', 'enqueue_styles'), 999);
        remove_action('wp_head', array('easyFancyBox', 'main_script'), 999);
        remove_action('wp_print_scripts', array('easyFancyBox', 'register_scripts'), 999);
        remove_action('wp_footer', array('easyFancyBox', 'enqueue_footer_scripts'));
        remove_action('wp_footer', array('easyFancyBox', 'on_ready'), 999);
    }
}
```

And i have the following bit of script in my public.js file

```
$('#lightbox').hammer().on("swipe", function (event) {
                if (event.gesture.direction === 4) {
                    $('#lightbox a.lb-prev').trigger('click');
                } else if (event.gesture.direction === 2) {
                    $('#lightbox a.lb-next').trigger('click');
                }
            });


});
```

So i get no errors on the site but nothing happens. No mobile swipe functionality currently exists.

Answer (score 0):

Added the following

```
<?php
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

// BEGIN ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
// AUTO GENERATED - Do not modify or remove comment markers above or below:

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_light', 20 );
function theme_light() {



wp_enqueue_style( 'lightbox', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/lightbox.css', array(), '4.3.0' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'lightbox2',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/lightbox.js', array( 'jquery' ), '3.3.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script('swiper', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js/hammer.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.0', true);
 wp_enqueue_script('swiper1', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js/jquery.hammer.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.0', true);
/*wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/public.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true); */     




}




// END ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION




if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css' ) ):
    function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array( 'bootstrap','font-awesome' ) );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css', 10 );

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts', 30 );
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'simpleshift_public' );


     wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/public.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true);
}

add_action('wp_head','my_conditional_script',0);


function my_conditional_script() {
    if ( is_page('magdalena-morey') || ('ophelia-redpath') || ('john-glover') ) {
        remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array('easyFancyBox', 'enqueue_styles'), 999);
        remove_action('wp_head', array('easyFancyBox', 'main_script'), 999);
        remove_action('wp_print_scripts', array('easyFancyBox', 'register_scripts'), 999);
        remove_action('wp_footer', array('easyFancyBox', 'enqueue_footer_scripts'));
        remove_action('wp_footer', array('easyFancyBox', 'on_ready'), 999);
    }
}
```